# Heroku and Static HTML

Tags: heroku

If I run a website that contains a lot of static HTML code + JSON data then is there a way to have heroku serve HTML files directly without having to use it's Rack stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. 
Two common options are to either:

1. Use Rack::Cache to speed up the access time
2. Host the files on S3 and serve a redirect to the S3
   URL.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation or a tutorial about how to host assets and static files with Heroku using S3?

Comment: If your page is very static, you can just manually upload your assets to S3. This seem to be a easy way when you have a small site with few number of image.